# How to add two messages to the messagehandler in delphi?

Tags: delphi

In the declaration of my form,I made a messagehandler:

```
procedure MessageHandler(var Msg:TMessage);Message MSG_ACCESS;

const
MSG_ASYNC = $BAD;
MSG_ACCESS = $BEEF;
```

In the message Handler when I check for a message,it works fine,but if i change the declaration like this:

```
procedure MessageHandler(var Msg:TMessage);Message MSG_ACCESS or MSG_ASYNC;
```

None of the messages I send are being handled.

How do I make it with two messages?

Comment: Your choice of message constants is highly dangerous, because there are certain ranges for system messages, others for user messages. If you choose a cute word in hex notation that happens to be one of the important Windows system messages you may completely break your application. You should use messages in the designated user range only (WM_USER + n), or register custom windows messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create two message handlers to call the shared one.

```
Procedure MessageHandler(var Msg:tMessage);
begin
  // your code here
end;

Procedure MsgAccessHandler(var Msg:Tmessage); message MSG_ACCESS;
begin
  MessageHandler(Msg);
end;

Procedure MsgAsyncHandler(Var Msg:tMessage); message MSG_ASYNC;
begin
  MessageHandler(Msg);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The OR operator in Pascal acts as both a logical and binary OR (|| and |) depending on context. So MSG_ACCESS or MSG_ASYNC is $0BAD OR $BEEF = $BFEF (0x0BAD | 0xBEEF).

So you are trying to handle a Message $BFEF

Another method is to use a MessageHook routine

function MsgHook(var Message: TMessage): Boolean;

in the form create use

```
Application.HookMainWindow(MsgHook);
```

ensure you unhook it in the destructor

```
  Application.UnhookMainWindow(MsgHook);

function TFormMain.MsgHook(var Message: TMessage): Boolean;
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    MSG_ACCESS :
    begin
      // what ever
    end;
    MSG_ASYNC:
    begin
      // what ever
    end;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

It is also possible to override the WndProc for the form:

```
procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
```